# How to add an audio file to React konva?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

I am trying to make a site like office 365 PowerPoint. I started using React konva. I got stucked on adding audio file to konva stage with new layer. I searched alot butcan't found solution. I should be able to add an audio file and adjust its volume.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `react-konva` for that. `react-konva` can be used to visualize your page.

For the sound, you can just create `<audio />` element outside of canvas `<Stage/>` and controls its volume.

```js
const Audio = ({ src, isPlaying }) => {
  const audioRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current.play();
    } else {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    }
  });

  return <audio src={src} ref={audioRef} />;
};
```